# Big battery usage

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.1-jelly-bean, battery-life

I have Galaxy s2 running android 4.1.2.

My phone can eat near to 25% battery in 6h – and during this time I spend only ~5minutes on Facebook. I downloaded  Wakeuplock and it shows that Google+ is running for 30minutes and keeping my phone wake. Here's a screenshot screen:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

As you can see Activ parameter is over 20% ( so its bad as someone told me).
Can you suggest me something how to improve batery life.

Phone is on the `battery save` mode all time.

Comment: 27% drain in almost 7 hours is not *that* bad, to be honest.

Comment: 25% -7h in which i used facebook for5 minutes and checked buses  and listening radio for 2 isn't that bad? 95% time this phone is idle with battery saving on

Comment: A smartphone with the battery lasting more than 24h is very good, honestly. Many people have trouble to get home before the battery runs out... Are you using the G+ app, or would "disabling" it be an option to you?

Comment: I today lunched this app for the first time to check if it's sharing my location xD. If it's possible I'll delete it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state you don't even need "that app", here are two approaches to keep it from eating your battery:

#### Disabling the app

1. Go to *Settings → Apps*, select the "All" tab
2. Scroll to the app in question (in the current example, *Google+*)
3. Tapp its entry to open the details
4. Tapp the "Force Close" button to end all its processes
5. Optionally, tapp the "Clear Cache" and "Delete Data" buttons to free some space on the device
6. If you see a button labeled "Uninstall Updates"<sup>1</sup>, tapp it. The button will then rename itself to...
7. Tapp the "Disable"<sup>1</sup> button<sup>2</sup>

The app should no longer start itself now, and thus not eat any battery anymore. If you need it back at a later point in time, it's still listed in *Settings→Apps* (though it might have been moved to the very end of the list). Opening its entry should show a button labeled "Enable" now, which speaks for itself.

#### Keep the app from running when you don't need it

On the playstore, you will find an app named [Greenify](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.oasisfeng.greenify). This can be used to automatically "hibernate" an app when its not running in foreground. Though *Greenify* is delivering its full potential benefits only with "root powers", it can do many things already without. If its free version cannot deal with the app in question (Google+ here), you might need the [Donation package](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.oasisfeng.greenify.pro) (for ~USD 3), which has additional ways to force apps into "hibernation".

[image: Greenify Start Screen] [image: Greenify App Analyzer]
<sup>Greenify: Start screen, App Analyzer (Source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> If you have none of the two buttons, but an "Uninstall" button, it's no system app: simply uninstall it.

<sup>2</sup> Note that not all system apps permit this (button is grayed out then).

Answer (score 0):

In Google+ app, go to `Settings` -> [your account name] -> `Location Sharing` and disable it.  In my personal experience, this is by far the worst offender in terms of battery drain.

If you have automatic photo backup enabled, you may want to restrict this feature to only when the phone is on the charger by going to `Settings -> Auto Backup` and enabling the `While charging only` option.

Comment: `Location sharing` was off. I have nothing like `Auto backup` in the menu. I don't have any photo backup.

Comment: The `Auto Backup` should be in the main Settings menu, right above your account name.

Comment: `Auto Backup` was disabled

Answer (score 0):

25% battery in 6h for a smartphone is good. A smartphone battery typically last less than 24 hours.

If you want to maximize your battery autonomy

- disable automatic sync
- disable Wifi, GPS, Bluetooth
- use minimum brightness for the screen. The screen is the bigger battery killer.

Comment: Smarphone is without Wifi/Gps/BT/Brightness all the time + energy saving mode

Comment: Then you did your best to improve your battery usage. Last thing you could do is block or uninstall all apps that could run in the background. Or unsolder unused component (speaker, Bluetooth, etc.) to prevent physical battery drain from these components, at your own risks.