# How do I prevent apps from waking up Sony Xperia 3 compact?

Tags: applications, battery-life, standby, wakelock

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 compact, with Android 5.1.1. This phone is not rooted, and actually belongs to a friend, so I cannot root this phone. I am having battery life problems that appear to be a result of the phone not sleeping correctly. In the battery indicator, the phone is shown to have been awake almost constantly over 16 hours, including overnight while charging, while the phone had its screen on for only the first hour of that time period.

The top battery hogs are:

1. Whatsapp 13%
2. Facebook 12%
3. Android OS 10%
4. Messenger 8%

I have already set the WiFi to never be on while asleep because I have previously had problems with this.

How do I prevent these apps and the Android OS from constantly waking the phone and draining the battery?

Comment: Is your phone rooted? If not: Either uninstall those apps or disable features like *synchronisation* or *Push messages*. If it is: get Greenify and add those apps to be hibernated.

Comment: Even if it is not, get Greenify (@GiantTree it meanwhile also works without root, though not with its full potential).

Comment: Related: [YouTube app holds a long wakelock. What app settings can I change to keep it from doing this?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/90154/16575) / [How to prevent apps and processes from launching in background and slowing my device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/87042/16575) / [Why is Youtube draining the battery and what could we do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/68360/16575) / [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/16575) / [Big battery usage](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/65240/16575)